# Microsoft Cognitive Speech Service - Android

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Microsoft Cognitive Services - Speech Recognition on an Android application. Everything works fine when the code is in my main activity, but when I want to move the part corresponding to speech recognition to a new class, it throws an error.

Here are the code samples:

**In the main activity**

```
int m_waitSeconds = 0;
MicrophoneRecognitionClient micClient = null;
FinalResponseStatus isReceivedResponse = FinalResponseStatus.NotReceived;
Boolean speechIntent = false;
SpeechRecognitionMode speechMode = SpeechRecognitionMode.ShortPhrase;

public enum FinalResponseStatus { NotReceived, OK }

/**
 * Gets the primary subscription key
 */
public String getPrimaryKey() {
    return this.getString(R.string.primaryKey);
}

/**
 * Gets the secondary subscription key
 */
public String getSecondaryKey() {
    return this.getString(R.string.secondaryKey);
}

/**
 * Gets the LUIS application identifier.
 * @return The LUIS application identifier.
 */
private String getLuisAppId() {
    return this.getString(R.string.luisAppID);
}

/**
 * Gets the LUIS subscription identifier.
 * @return The LUIS subscription identifier.
 */
private String getLuisSubscriptionID() {
    return this.getString(R.string.luisSubscriptionID);
}

/**
 * Gets the default locale.
 * @return The default locale.
 */
private String getDefaultLocale() {
    return "en-us";
}


/**
 * Handles the Click event of the _startButton control.
 */
private void StartButton_Click(View v) {

    this.m_waitSeconds = this.speechMode == SpeechRecognitionMode.ShortPhrase ? 20 : 200;

    if (this.micClient == null) {
        if (this.speechIntent) {
            this.WriteLine("--- Start microphone dictation with Intent detection ----");

            this.micClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createMicrophoneClientWithIntent(
                            this,
                            this.getDefaultLocale(),
                            this,
                            this.getPrimaryKey(),
                            this.getSecondaryKey(),
                            this.getLuisAppId(),
                            this.getLuisSubscriptionID());
        }
        else
        {
            this.micClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createMicrophoneClient(
                    this,
                    this.speechMode,
                    this.getDefaultLocale(),
                    this,
                    this.getPrimaryKey(),
                    this.getSecondaryKey());
        }
    }

    this.micClient.startMicAndRecognition();
}

public void onFinalResponseReceived(final RecognitionResult response) {
    boolean isFinalDicationMessage = this.speechMode == SpeechRecognitionMode.LongDictation &&
            (response.RecognitionStatus == RecognitionStatus.EndOfDictation ||
                    response.RecognitionStatus == RecognitionStatus.DictationEndSilenceTimeout);
    if (null != this.micClient && ((this.speechMode == SpeechRecognitionMode.ShortPhrase) || isFinalDicationMessage)) {
        // we got the final result, so it we can end the mic reco.  No need to do this
        // for dataReco, since we already called endAudio() on it as soon as we were done
        // sending all the data.
        this.micClient.endMicAndRecognition();
    }

    if (isFinalDicationMessage) {
        this.isReceivedResponse = FinalResponseStatus.OK;
    }

    Confidence cMax = Confidence.Low;
    int iMax = 0;
    if (!isFinalDicationMessage && response.Results.length != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < response.Results.length; i++) {
            //get the text with highest confidence:
            if(response.Results[i].Confidence.getValue() > cMax.getValue()){
                cMax = response.Results[i].Confidence;
                iMax = i;
            }
        }
        this.WriteLine(response.Results[iMax].DisplayText);
    }

}



/**
 * Called when a final response is received and its intent is parsed
 */

public void onIntentReceived(final String payload) {
    this.WriteLine("--- Intent received by onIntentReceived() ---");
    this.WriteLine(payload);
    this.WriteLine();
}

public void onPartialResponseReceived(final String response) {
    this.WriteLine("--- Partial result received by onPartialResponseReceived() ---");
    this.WriteLine(response);
    this.WriteLine();
}

public void onError(final int errorCode, final String response) {
    this.WriteLine("--- Error received by onError() ---");
    this.WriteLine("Error code: " + SpeechClientStatus.fromInt(errorCode) + " " + errorCode);
    this.WriteLine("Error text: " + response);
    this.WriteLine();
}

/**
 * Called when the microphone status has changed.
 * @param recording The current recording state
 */
public void onAudioEvent(boolean recording) {
    if (!recording) {
        this.micClient.endMicAndRecognition();
    }
}

/**
 * Writes the line.
 */
private void WriteLine() {
    this.WriteLine("");
}

/**
 * Writes the line.
 * @param text The line to write.
 */
private void WriteLine(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

**In a separate class**

```
public class SpeechRecognition implements ISpeechRecognitionServerEvents 
{
int m_waitSeconds = 0;
private MicrophoneRecognitionClient micClient = null;
private FinalResponseStatus isReceivedResponse =FinalResponseStatus.NotReceived;

private Boolean speechIntent = false;
private SpeechRecognitionMode speechMode=SpeechRecognitionMode.ShortPhrase;

public enum FinalResponseStatus { NotReceived, OK }

/**
 * Gets the primary subscription key
 */
public String getPrimaryKey() {
    return Integer.toString(R.string.primaryKey);
}
/**
 * Gets the secondary subscription key
 */
public String getSecondaryKey() {
    return Integer.toString(R.string.secondaryKey);
}

/**
 * Gets the LUIS application identifier.
 * @return The LUIS application identifier.
 */
private String getLuisAppId() {
    return Integer.toString(R.string.luisAppID);
}

/**
 * Gets the LUIS subscription identifier.
 * @return The LUIS subscription identifier.
 */
private String getLuisSubscriptionID() {
    return Integer.toString(R.string.luisSubscriptionID);
}

/**
 * Gets the default locale.
 * @return The default locale.
 */
private String getDefaultLocale() {
    return "en-us";
}

public void startSpeechRecognition() {

    this.m_waitSeconds = this.speechMode == SpeechRecognitionMode.ShortPhrase ? 20 : 200;

    if (this.micClient == null) {
        if (this.speechIntent) {
            this.micClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createMicrophoneClientWithIntent(
                            this.getDefaultLocale(),
                            this,
                            this.getPrimaryKey(),
                            this.getSecondaryKey(),
                            this.getLuisAppId(),
                            this.getLuisSubscriptionID());
        }
        else
        {
            this.micClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createMicrophoneClient(
                    this.speechMode,
                    this.getDefaultLocale(),
                    this,
                    this.getPrimaryKey(),
                    this.getSecondaryKey());

        }
    }

    this.micClient.startMicAndRecognition();


}

public void endSpeechRecognition(){
    this.micClient.endMicAndRecognition();
}


public void onFinalResponseReceived(final RecognitionResult response) {
    boolean isFinalDicationMessage = this.speechMode == SpeechRecognitionMode.LongDictation &&
            (response.RecognitionStatus == RecognitionStatus.EndOfDictation ||
                    response.RecognitionStatus == RecognitionStatus.DictationEndSilenceTimeout);
    if (null != this.micClient && ((this.speechMode == SpeechRecognitionMode.ShortPhrase) || isFinalDicationMessage)) {
        // we got the final result, so it we can end the mic reco.  No need to do this
        // for dataReco, since we already called endAudio() on it as soon as we were done
        // sending all the data.
        this.micClient.endMicAndRecognition();
    }

    if (isFinalDicationMessage) {
        this.isReceivedResponse = FinalResponseStatus.OK;
    }

    Confidence cMax = Confidence.Low;
    int iMax = 0;
    if (!isFinalDicationMessage && response.Results.length != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < response.Results.length; i++) {
            //get the text with highest confidence:
            if(response.Results[i].Confidence.getValue() > cMax.getValue()){
                cMax = response.Results[i].Confidence;
                iMax = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Action to take: " + response.Results[iMax].DisplayText);
    }

}

/**
 * Called when a final response is received and its intent is parsed
 */
public void onIntentReceived(final String payload) {
    System.out.println("--- Intent received by onIntentReceived() ---");
    System.out.println(payload);
}

public void onPartialResponseReceived(final String response) {
    System.out.println("--- Partial result received by onPartialResponseReceived() ---");
    System.out.println(response);
}

public void onError(final int errorCode, final String response) {
    System.err.println("--- Error received by onError() ---");
    System.err.println("Error code: " + SpeechClientStatus.fromInt(errorCode) + " " + errorCode);
    System.err.println("Error text: " + response);
}

/**
 * Called when the microphone status has changed.
 * @param recording The current recording state
 */
public void onAudioEvent(boolean recording) {
    System.out.println("--- Microphone status change received by onAudioEvent() ---");
    System.out.println("********* Microphone status: " + recording + " *********");
    if (recording) {
        System.out.println("Please start speaking.");
    }

    if (!recording) {
        this.micClient.endMicAndRecognition();
    }
}
```

}

You can clearly see that it is basically the same code but it gives me this error in the onError function after i call      this.micClient.startMicAndRecognition();
:

```
Error code: LoginFailed -1910505470
```

Comment: Are you intentionally using different `createMicrophoneClient` constructors in the new class? Have you tested those constructors in the original class?

Comment: Yes I am intentionally using a different constructor due to the fact that it does not need an Activity as a parameter. Anyway I tried both constructors in the main activity and they work just fine.
When it comes to the error it pops up when I start recording not when I try to create a MicClient, the constructor returns a micClient. @brandall

Comment: Ok. Then all that is left is a threading issue? Try running the code from the UI thread and then test a background thread. Ensure you're not calling the constructor and `startSpeechRecognition` from different threads. Test setting `MicrophoneRecognitionClient` to `volatile` if that is your intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I was getting a wrong Primary key in this line of code:

```
public String getPrimaryKey() {
    return Integer.toString(R.string.primaryKey);
}
```

It is because the primary key is too long to be read by the processor as an integer then transformed to a String. I had to get the primary key from the main activity via ***getString(R.string.primaryKey)*** then pass it as a parameter to the constructor of the SpeechRecognition class.